# ad library API with python

Tags: python, parsing

Is there anyone you had an expirience with working with ad libray API through python (for example with requests or etc) and with integration it into your own projects? I just need several examples how to release it clearly

i just have received the access to the ad library API and don't know how to use it right

i have some code on python but i'm getting empty data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRe19.png)

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation.

Comment: Are you asking about the [Meta Ad Library API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/ads_archive/)

Comment: yep, i'm about Meta Ad Library API

Comment: i actually read the doc. and even got some results in my pyhon code. In fact im getting 200 responce.status however responce.json() is just simply empty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.